# Problem create chart from scratch with Apache Poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, apache-poi-4, xslf

When I create a chart from scratch and add it to a slide within a PowerPoint using Apache Poi the corresponding `XSLFGraphicFrame` shape get created and added to the XML but it doesn't get added to the `getShapes()` list within the slide, things that happen correctly for the other shapes type, is there any way to ascend the dependency tree up to the `GraphicalFrame` and get the corresponding `XSLFShape` object and add it by hand?

**Example:**
Assume I have an `XMLSlideShow` object that we call ppt, ppt has an `XSLFSLide` object representing its slide in first position. So now this slide has some shapes. let's say these are 2 XSLFTextBox, that we can iterate over using method `getShapes()`.

So if we create a chart from scratch:

```
//ppt.getSlides().get(0).getShapes().foreach .... sysout of each shapes produce something like shape1, shape2 we assumed before
XSLFChart chart = ppt.createChart(ppt.getSlides().get(0); //so adding the relation part to the first slide of our ppt
ppt.getSlides().get(0).addChart(chart, anchor); // we add the chart to the slide at some anchor we r interesting at
//now here do all things you need to populate your chart with data
//now ppt.getSlides().get(0).getShapes(). foreach .... sysout of this still produce shape1, shape2 and exclude shape3 (the actual just created chart)
```

But if we loop over XML objects bean we can actually find the graphical frame object that seems to not be added to the getShapes list.

How can I manually do this by first getting the corresponding shape?

**EDIT**: I managed to resolve the problem with a work-around since is too much work to edit the source code and rebuild the lib with ant+gradle etc etc. The ppt can be loaded from a stream, which is done by reading the xml file, which correctly lists the graphic frame. I wrote the ppt in a ByteArrayOutputStream and reload it from an input stream over the byte array; this fixed the problem.